# Importing a package from within a directory fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, codebase

I have a project directory structure as follows:

```
rootdir/
somefile.py
- proj/
  - __init__.py
  - __main__.py
  - file1.py
  - file2.py
```

file2 has an import, `from file1 import some_module`

When I am in rootdir and I call something like `import proj.file2.bla_bla as bla_bla from somefile.py`

I get an error like

**error in file2**

> cannot find file1 or no such module such as file1

What do you think is going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0):

if you are running the program from rootdir like

python3 rootdir/somefile.py

then you can import file1 in file2 as follows

from project.file1 import something

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure that in file2:

```
from file1 import some_module
```

becomes

```
from .file1 import some_module
```